What does the bank actually do with a debt that can never be collected?
Let's say the bank has come to the conclusion that the person is not going to pay his debt. -Died without assets, alive but in Siberia for 20 years, in a very, very bad medical condition.
What does the bank actually do? Just delete his debt from his asset line?
or in other words, unpaid debt don't affect the bank too much in the end?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance, and the answer depends on a lot of missing details (jurisdictions, for starters).

If the bank has no reasonable expectation of collecting on a debt, it is "written off" as a "bad debt" expense and removed from the bank's assets on its balance sheet. It can also try to sell that debt to a third party ("debt collector") who will attempt to collect all or part of the debt for a profit.

in other words, unpaid debt don't affect the bank too much in the end?

Not true - this is like saying that you not getting paid for your work doesn't affect you because you'll have the same money that you have now. You have bills to pay just like the bank, so an unpaid debt affects the bank's ability to lend out more money, pay for its expenses, etc.
Granted, one unpaid debt will not bring down a bank, but too much unpaid debt will have a significant impact on its financial health.

Whatever they do with it, the difference between the debt on balance sheet and the amount they sell it for (or zero if they write it off themselves) is going to be a loss in that financial period. Banks do reserve for bad debts however, see that as a method to spread the losses over time so that no large spikes occur. Of course, any decent analyst will poke at that reserve as well to try and figure out what's going on.

united-states
As with almost all private debt in the US, the debt is generally sold to a debt collection company for pennies on the dollar, often as a bundle of "good" and "bad" debt (good and bad relative here, since the debts are being sent to collections so to speak, so technically none of them are actually good). The debt collection company acquires collectible debts along side the uncollectible debts which allows the bank (or other debt holding company) to clear the bad debt on their balance sheets, while still potentially being profitable for the debt collector.

From an accountancy point of view, let's say there are $25,000 that they are not going to collect. So in their books they subtract $25,000 from "debt owed to bank" and add $25,000 to "debt not recoverable", because the books have to balance. And when it's time to calculate the assets of the bank, the "debt owed to bank" would have been an asset, but "debt not recoverable" isn't, so the bank's assets are $25,000 less than they would have liked. And profits will be $25,000 lower, which means the tax they have to pay on their profits is lower, which will also go into their books.

debt not recoverable would be an expense, basically a write-off.
